# TypeScript based Promise/A+ compliant, awaitable promise class for Node.js

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, typescript

This is yet another Node.js Promise implementation, but this is written in TypeScript, and it strives for type safety and clarity. The full project is located [here](https://github.com/llint/PromiseX). Feel free to download it and test it out.

Please give your comments regarding any missing bits or errors, as well as any potential improvements (I'm only 5 days into Node/TypeScript/JavaScript).

```
function isPromiseLike<T>(x: any): x is PromiseLike<T> {
    return x != null && (<PromiseLike<T>>x).then != undefined;
}

function isPromiseX<T>(x: PromiseLike<T>): x is PromiseX<T> {
    return x != null && (<PromiseX<T>>x).type == PromiseX.symbolPromiseX;
}

enum State { Pending, Fulfilled, Rejected }

export class PromiseX<T = any> implements PromiseLike<T> {
    static symbolPromiseX: symbol = Symbol('PromiseX');
    readonly type: symbol = PromiseX.symbolPromiseX;

    private _state: State = State.Pending;

    private _result: T;

    private _reason: any;

    private _continuations: [(x: T) => void, (e: any) => void][] = [];

    constructor(executor?: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void) {
        if (executor) {
            executor(result => this.setResult(result), error => this.setError(error));
        }
    }

    // if 'result' is 'undefined', it'll be passed along
    // Note that there is a potential race if the current state is pending, while
    // someone calls setResult on two different PromiseLike values - the first one
    // gets either fulfilled or rejected would set the current promise in a non-pending state,
    // and the second PromiseLike when eventually becomes non-pending would call either setResult or setError
    // but find the state becomes non-pending, thus would have no effect!
    public setResult(result?: T | PromiseLike<T>): void {
        if (this._state == State.Pending) {
            if (isPromiseLike(result)) {
                result.then(x => this.setResult(x), e => this.setError(e));
            } else {
                this._state = State.Fulfilled;
                this._result = result;
                for (let continuation of this._continuations) {
                    continuation[0](this._result);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public setError(reason?: any): void {
        if (this._state == State.Pending) {
            this._state = State.Rejected;
            this._reason = reason;
            for (let continuation of this._continuations) {
                continuation[1](this._reason);
            }
        }
    }

    then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(onFulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | undefined | null, onRejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | undefined | null): PromiseX<TResult1 | TResult2> {
        switch (this._state) {
            case State.Fulfilled: {
                let r : TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>;
                if (onFulfilled) {
                    try {
                        r = onFulfilled(this._result);
                    } catch (e) {
                        let p = new PromiseX<never>();
                        p.setError(e);
                        return p;
                    }
                }
                if (isPromiseLike(r) && isPromiseX(r)) {
                    return r;
                }
                let p = new PromiseX<TResult1>();
                p.setResult(r);
                return p;
            }

            case State.Rejected: {
                if (onRejected) {
                    let r : TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>;
                    try {
                        r = onRejected(this._reason);
                    } catch (e) {
                        let p = new PromiseX<never>();
                        p.setError(e);
                        return p;
                    }
                    if (isPromiseLike(r) && isPromiseX(r)) {
                        return r;
                    }
                    let p = new PromiseX<TResult2>();
                    p.setResult(r); // NB: the error has been handled, we pass along the handled result
                    return p;
                }
                let p = new PromiseX<TResult2>();
                p.setError(this._reason); // NB: the error is not handled, mark the returned promise to be the same error, so it can be passed along until handled
                return p;
            }

            case State.Pending: {
                let p = new PromiseX<TResult1 | TResult2>();
                this._continuations.push([
                    result => {
                        let r : TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>;
                        if (onFulfilled) {
                            try {
                                r = onFulfilled(result);
                            } catch (e) {
                                p.setError(e);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        p.setResult(r);
                    },
                    reason => {
                        if (onRejected) {
                            let r : TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>;
                            try {
                                r = onRejected(reason);
                            } catch (e) {
                                p.setError(e);
                                return;
                            }
                            p.setResult(r);
                        } else {
                            p.setError(reason); // NB: error not handled, pass the error along the chain
                        }
                    }
                ]);
                return p;
            }
        }
    }

    catch<TResult = never>(onRejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>) | undefined | null): PromiseX<T | TResult> {
        return this.then(undefined, onRejected);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a few notes from your GitHub project

1. The most important compiler option to turn on is `strict`. This protects you from many common errors and makes it much nicer when defining optional type parameters. After turning on strict mode, the `| undefined` part can be dropped from parameters. (Personally, I'd like to also drop `null` to enforce the use of a consistent. See [null is bad](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/null.html))
2. Consider using a proper testing framework, tests should ideally be quick and easy to read to see exactly what the code should be doing. The current testing code prints out a bunch of numbers without telling me for sure if everything is working or not. I will recommend [Ava](https://github.com/avajs/ava) (potentially along with `ava-ts`) for the convenience of how it is designed to be used with promises. You could also just use [this project](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-tests) to test your implementation.

Now on to your code :) In no particular order...

1. Instead of defining a `isPromiseX` function, you might consider implementing the [`Symbol.hasInstance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/hasInstance) method and just using `if (x instanceof PromiseX)`
2. With the default promise implementation in Chrome at least, if the passed `executor` function throws an error, the promise will be rejected. (Does not seem to be covered by the spec). It might be worth duplicating this behavior.
3. `setResult` and `setError` should not be public. They are only used internally.
4. I prefer early returns to nested code, in every case where you wrap a function's body with `if (this._state == State.Pending)`, I would prefer to check if the state is not pending and return.
5. The code is not fully spec compliant. See point [2.3.1](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-48) is not fulfilled.
6. Instead of defining `setResult` and `setError` as prototype methods, since you pass them into functions it may be worth defining them with arrow functions as demonstrated [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html).

   ```ts
   private setResult = (result?: T | PromiseLike<T>): void => {
   ```

Good work on the implementation overall!

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Gerrit0! I’ll explore the Symbol system and it seems using instanceof is a more intuitive way of doing type guards. This implementation is meant for node.js and server side, so chrome compatibility is not my greatest concern, but your point is taken as a good reference. setResult/setError are public for convenience testing things, so I don’t have to hook them to another “producer”. I like early return too. Honestly, I didn’t really read through the resolution spec, the implementation was largely based on “common sense”, I’ll read through the spec though.

Comment: Regarding the arrow function, I’m still not too clear regarding the difference between the way I defined them vs the arrow function approach: for the arrow function approach, can I pass “this.setResult” around? Because I knew when I defined it my way, the “this” context was lost, thats why I had to use a closure to wrap it. Thanks again for your suggestions!

Comment: Oh, regarding the first point (having extra `undefined` and `null` union types), the reason is that I'm actually implementing the TypeScript defined `PromiseLike<T>` interface, whose `then` method is defined exactly like that. I was not too sure if I should just omit the `undefined` and `null` type, so I just included them in, and didn't bother too much.

Comment: Arrow functions: [see the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20test%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(this)%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)